# Check if item is in ParamArray VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing a function to run some macros on all sheets of a workbook except a list of excluded sheets. I'm passing the list of excluded sheets as a ParamArray but am having trouble checking the current worksheet against the list in the ParamArray.

```
Public Sub RunThingsOnSheets(ParamArray excludedSheets())

Dim ws as Worksheet
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws Not In excludedSheets Then  'In Pseudocode this is what I want
        "do things"
    End If
Next ws

End Sub

Public Sub Test()

Call RunThingsOnSheets(SheetOne, SheetTwo)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Public Sub RunThingsOnSheets(ParamArray excludedSheets())
Dim ws As Worksheet, o, inList As Boolean

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        inList = False
        For Each o In excludedSheets
            If o.Name = ws.Name Then
                inList = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If Not inList Then
            Debug.Print "not in excludedsheets: " & ws.Name
        End If
    Next ws

End Sub

Public Sub Test()

    RunThingsOnSheets Sheet1, Sheet3

End Sub
```

Comment: Was just about to post virtually the same thing but was going to explain about ws.Name and ws.CodeName since the OP didn't quote the worksheet name/codename that they were trying to pass across.

Comment: I assumed that the OP meant to pass the sheet object references directly, and not as a string (Name/Codename)

Comment: OK, I didn't think of that. Like Set SheetOne = Worksheets(1). I took it to be misspelled worksheet codenames.

Comment: This idea of using a boolean flag worked for me and was easy to understand. Re: the name vs code name discussion, I have only worked with sheets two ways: directly by index (Worksheets(i)), or by building a string with the worksheet names and then splitting the string and selecting them (ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Split(sheetList, separation character)).Select). I'm not sure what ws.CodeName refers to or if there is a more preferred method to work with sheets.

Comment: CodeName refers to the name of the sheet in the properties pane of the VBA editor. If you name your sheets this way, you can refer to them directly in code without going through the Sheets collection.

Comment: I've been working in VBA for a while and my personal preference is to refer to sheets by ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Name"). I don't bother with CodeNames and going through ThisWorkbook is a bit more reliable when you're not certain what the active workbook could be.

Answer (score 2):

It's useful to have a general purpose array search function when working with VBA as part of your toolkit, since there isn't one built into the language.

```
Public Function ArraySearch(ByVal a As Variant, v As Variant, _
                            Optional ByRef found_index As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim i As Long

    ArraySearch = False

    If Not IsArray(a) Then Exit Function

    For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
        If (VarType(a(i)) And vbArray) <> 0 Then
            ' Don't compare arrays
        ElseIf (VarType(v) And vbArray) <> 0 Then
            ' Don't compare arrays
        ElseIf VarType(a(i)) = VarType(v) Then
            If IsObject(v) Then
                If a(i) Is v Then
                    ArraySearch = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            ElseIf a(i) = v Then
                ArraySearch = True
                Exit For
            End If
        ElseIf VarType(a(i)) = vbError Or _
            VarType(v) = vbError Or _
            VarType(a(i)) = vbObject Or _
            VarType(v) = vbObject _
        Then
            ' Guard against type mismatch
        ElseIf a(i) = v Then
            ArraySearch = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    If ArraySearch And Not IsMissing(found_index) Then found_index = i
End Function
```

Then you can search a ParamArray using this function.

```
Public Sub RunThingsOnSheets(ParamArray excludedSheets())
    Dim ws as Worksheet

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets: Do
        If ArraySearch(excludedSheets, ws) Then Exit Do

        ' do things
    Loop While False: Next
End Sub
```

Two notes:

1. I used an [idiom to simulate C's "continue" statement](/a/3944610/45084) in this For Each loop. You may or may not appreciate this depending on your programming style preferences.
2. This ArraySearch implementation passes the array by value. This is necessary to support ParamArrays. But if you regularly use it to search huge arrays of thousands of elements, passing by value here might create a memory or performance issue.